Struggling with modular arithmetic problems.
I've been struggling with this modular arithmetic problem for a while, I could solve the simpler problems where we have to find out what day it is or what hour is is after a certain amount of time has passed but I can not wrap my head around this problem from my past quiz, where do we start, how do we go around and solve this?
Any sort of help is appreciated.
Question
Assume that you are given the task to mark maths exams. Every script takes you 7
minutes to mark. You need to mark $ 56 ^{27} $ scripts. If you start at midnight, at what minute past the hour will you be done? For example, if you finish five days later at 11:23 am, then this counts as 23 minutes past the hour.

Please edit to include your efforts.  Have you, for example, translated this into a congruence problem?

Yes that's precisely it, I couldn't make any solid efforts and I am not sure as to how to turn this into a congruency problem I tried to work with modulo 7 but I didn't get anywhere for regular problems including days I always used modulo 7 but I am not sure as to how to tackle this problems.

Why $\pmod 7$?  $\quad$

I am not too sure since they said it takes 7 minutes to mark a certain script, I also thought of using modulo 24 to get the number of hours it takes but that would just give me the number of hours according to the number of scripts, its very confusing

A suggestion:  Try a simpler problem, same thing with fewer papers.  Say you had only one paper.  What's the answer?  Now say you had $9$ papers, what's the answer?  That should show you what congruence to write down.

The number of hours is irrelevant.  Try my suggestion.  The case of $9$ papers is the first interesting one.  Why?

Look at the one sentence that expresses the question. It asks, “At what minute…?” So, minute within which repeating cycle? How often does that cycle bring the number of minutes back to 0?

As a side note to math educators: this problem is an example of how terrible we are at making "real world" problems. This is not even close to a realistic situation—we would never have that many exam papers, and if we did we would never count them in that way. When we make "real world" problems that are ridiculous, it both hinders students' learning and turns them off of math, by reinforcing their beliefs that it's useless to try to incorporate intuition into mathematical calculations.

Once you realize that the correct period modulus  is $60$ (= number of minutes in an hour) then it reduces to a standard modular powering problem. See the linked dupe for many method (e.g. see my comment on ράτ's answer for one simple way). $\ \ $

Thanks a lot I was looking for that I did identify the period to be 60 but was struggling with the modular powering.

you need to mark $56^{27}$ scripts and each one of these takes you $7$ minutes so the total time should be $56^{27}\times7$ minutes. Since we do not care what hour we finish (finishing at $11:57$ and $03:57$ gives the exact same result). So it is obvious we need to work $\mod 60$. In other words we need to evaluate $$56^{27}
\cdot7 \mod 60$$
Remember that $(a\cdot b) \mod c= ((a \mod c)\cdot(b \mod c)) \mod c$ . Therefore we get
$$((56^{27}
 \mod 60)\cdot(7 \mod 60))\mod 60\\(((56^2)^{13}\cdot56 \mod 60)\cdot7)\mod 60$$
Apply the same rule again and get :
$$(((((56^2 )^{13}\mod 60\cdot (56 \mod 60))\mod 60)\cdot 7)\mod 60$$
Also remember: $(a^b)\mod c=((a\mod c)^b)\mod c$. Here  we get
$$((((((56^2\mod60)^{13}\mod60)\cdot56)\mod60)\cdot7)\mod60\\(((((3136\mod60)^{13})\mod60)\cdot56)\mod60)\cdot7)\mod60\\((((16^{13}\mod60)\cdot56)\mod60)\cdot7)\mod60$$ We can write $16^{13}=(16^2)^6\cdot 16$ and apply the two modulo rules , the product and exponent one respectively and get:
$$((((((16^2\cdot16\mod60)\cdot(16\mod60))\mod60)\cdot16)\mod60)\cdot56)\mod60)\cdot7)\mod60$$ These are really easy to compute and get to :
$$((16\cdot56\mod60)\cdot7)\mod60\\((896\mod60)\cdot7)\mod60\\392\mod60\\=32$$

Easier $!\bmod 60!:\ 7(-4)^{\large 27}\overset{\color{darkorange}{\rm D}}\equiv \color{#0a0}4(-7(\color{#c00}{(-4)^{\large 2}})^{\large 13}\bmod 15)\equiv 4(-7\cdot\color{#c00}1) \equiv 32,,$ by $,\color{#c00}{4^2\equiv 1}\pmod{!15},,$ where we have employed $,\color{darkorange}{\rm D} =$ mod Distributive law to factor out $,\color{#0a0}4\ \ $

That's great, thanks for the info!
